# Can I increment an SRAM address?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel

I have to write a program that can store consecutive integers starting with 11 up to 40 in SRAM starting from address 0x0200.

This is what I tried to do in Assembly language:

```
    LDI R16, 10
    LDI R17, 30             
   .EQU MEM = 0x0200      

L1: INC R16
    STS MEM, R16
    INC MEM
    DEC R17
    BRNE L1

L2: jmp L2
```

However, Atmel Studio doesn't allow me to increment the address. Is there any solution to this problem without having to type 30 STS's?

Comment: `MEM` is a literal. Load it to a register.

Comment: I am not trying to increment the value stored in MEM. I am trying to access the next address, which would be 0x0201

Comment: I understood that. But `MEM` is the literal value `0x0200`. You can't increment that. You need to load it to a register first.

Comment: How can I load back the new literal value to MEM? Let's say I loaded 0x0200 to a register and I am incrementing it so that it becomes 0x0201. Atmel Studio doesn't allow me to equate MEM with a register (e.g.    .equ MEM = R18)

Comment: it's the other way around... you create literal MEM = 0x200, then you load it into register like R18, and then you use R18 for STS (I don't know your CPU, if `STS R18,R16` is legal, or there's some other way how to use register value as memory reference for store). Then `inc R18` and loop.. `MEM` will be used only for that initial load.

Comment: You cannot load a value back to a literal value. Your `MEM` is comparable to a `#define MEM 0x0200` in C. Its an alias for the compiler/assembler. It'll be replaced by the literal value `0x0200`. If you need to change it, you need to store it in a register or in memory.

Comment: I cannot load 0x200 to a register apparently because it's out of range. The registers are 8-bit wide. And STS R18, R16 is illegal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code:

```
.EQU MEM = 0x0200
   ...
STS MEM, R16
INC MEM
```

... actually means:

```
STS 0x200, R16
INC 0x200
```

... and of course you cannot increment the constant 0x200. The constant 0x200 will always be 0x200; it will never be 0x201.

The `STS` instruction only allows you to store data to a **constant, fixed** address.

The `ST` instruction however allows you to specify the address in the `X` (R27:R26),  `Y` (R29:R28) or `Z` (R31:R30) register pairs.

In the case of `X` you *can* and in the case of `Y` and `Z` you *must* increment the address after the operation or decrement it before the operation. (And incrementing is exactly what you want.)

Example:

```
ST Y+, R16
```

If R29=2 and R28=0x34 before the instruction, this instruction will save R16 to 0x234 and R28 will be 0x35 after the instruction.

So the following program should work (unfortunately I'm not familiar with the AVR, so I'm not sure):

```
    LDI R29, 2    # High byte of "MEM"
    LDI R28, 0    # Low byte of "MEM"
L1: INC R16
    ST Y+, R16
    DEC R17
    BRNE L1
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. All the values were stored in consecutive memory locations.